# Unable to read out config file while iterating

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I am having trouble accessing an iterator when trying to read from a config file. My code is:

```
void requestPLC::write(QMap <QString, QVariant> map)
{

QMap<QString, QVariant>::iterator i;

for (i = map.begin(); i != map.end(); ++i)
    {
        mConfig->reqPLC->datatype.value(map[i]);
        // do something here
    }
}
```

What I want to do is iterate over my map and pick the corresponding value from the config file. My error looks like this:

> no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘QMap’
>   and ‘QMap::iterator’)
>                mConfig->reqPLC->datatype.value(map[i]);
>                                                      ^

I know this is caused by datatype.value(map[i]) being an iterator but I can't figure out a way to avoid this. Do I need to cast my iterator here or something?

Comment: try `i.value()` for value, or `i.key()` for the key

Comment: You need to give value of the iterator, not the iterator itself. In stl i would have done i->first for an iterator to map, in order to access the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the `key, value` of the `QMap` using an iterator
can be done via the [iterator class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap-iterator.html#value)

In your case:

```
void requestPLC::write(QMap <QString, QVariant> map)
{

    QMap<QString, QVariant>::iterator i;

    for (i = map.begin(); i != map.end(); ++i)
    {
        auto map_value = i.value();
        mConfig->reqPLC->datatype.value(map_value);
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give key from the iterator, not the iterator itself. In STL i would have done i->first for an iterator to map, in order to access the key, and i use the key to access the map using [] operator.